# Enable XDebug PHP debugger for only specific websites

Tags: php, .htaccess, xdebug, suphp

I'm running a CentOS web server with suPHP and I need to enable the XDebug PHP debugger for only a few select websites.  I've added the suPHP_ConfigPath setting in the .htaccess file so I can have a custom php.ini file for these websites, and I've added

> zend_extension="/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so"

to the custom php.ini file.  I've confirmed that it is indeed using the custom php.ini, however, when running phpinfo() it doesn't show that xdebug is enabled.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you restart Apache after editing the ini file?

Comment: Yes, a few times even.

Comment: At least, there are some commands missing. But, check this [link](http://xdebug.org/wizard.php). There is an application that helps you to install it according to `phpinfo()` results.